# Swift: Segue to a view programmatically from an alternate view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a master view, I have added in a menu (TableView) that slides out on an IBOutlet. This menu is controlled by another view controller. The master view is segued to multiple other views but I am having huge problems segueing from the menu view (TableView) because it is in another view controller.

How can I segue from master view to another view from my table which is controlled from yet another view controller?

Note: I am also having to carry over some information from master view to the other views, but I when ever I have tried to segue from the menu, the new views error and tell me they unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optionals.

Comment: Can you post the Prepare for segue method here ? and one screen shot of your story board ?

Comment: sometimes it is easier to present a view modally rather than segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your menu only post a notification when something is selected.  Have the view controller that's the source of the segue (master?) listen for the matching notification(s) and perform the segue.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I didn't think of this. This worked great, I called NSNotificattionCenter in my MainViewController which has a function containing a performSegue method. Then in my MenuViewController I Simply set a notification on the case for the respective cell in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Thank, this was annoying me no end!